# Image manipulation slow down response time. Image Intervention laravel

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I am using [Intervention/image][1] to process uploaded images, to create a thumbnail and a mid-sized version for each uploaded image. But the processing time takes on average about 7-10 seconds to complete single image.

How can i make it faster?

here is my code:

```
//CREATE IMAGE THUMBNAILS
        $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
        $img->resize(350, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
            $constraint->upsize();
        });

        $img->save($destinationPath.'/'.$input['thumbnail']);

        // Save Image As WebP
        $webp_img = Image::make($image->getRealPath())->encode('webp');
        $webp_img->save($destinationPath.'/'.$webp['name'].'.webp');

        $webp_img_thumb = Image::make($image->getRealPath())->encode('webp');
        $webp_img_thumb->resize(350, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
            $constraint->upsize();
        });
        $webp_img_thumb->save($destinationPath.'/'.$webp['thumbnail'].'.webp');

        $image->move($destinationPath, $temp_image->name);
```

Comment: sorry for not mentioning above i am working on api's.

Comment: Hi, please paste your code so we can see how you process the images.

Comment: 7-10 seconds is quite long, but suppose this got down to 2 seconds, would that be acceptable? Or, to put it in other words, what length of processing time would be acceptable to you? A second question would be: Why is 7-10 seconds too long?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware  think it's taking long time due image processing as i am resizing image and than encode both images to webp

Comment: @KFoobar i have edit my question so you can see my code now

Comment: I don't know anything about "intervention", but you seem to be doing the same resizing twice. That seems wasteful.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes that's for webp image thumbnail and does resizing image effect response time that bad?

Comment: Resizing images is always a lengthy procedure, so yes. But you're not getting to the point: Why do the same resize twice?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes i get your point that i am doing lengthy procedure (resizing image) twice but its for webp image format

Comment: You can resize once, and store in multiple formats. If that's what you want.

Comment: ok let me try this. thanks

Comment: @KIKOSoftware response time gets down to 4 to 8  seconds. This response time is for 4 mb images

Comment: Well, that's an improvement. But coming back to my first comment: What times are you aiming for and why?

Comment: I wonder how much, of that 4 to 8 seconds, is simply the time it takes to upload a 4 MB image.